# How to display selected row value/text inside the dropdown

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

So I am new to using ASP.net and i have a hard time displaying the value/text of the selected row inside the dropdown. I just want to select a row in the griview and when i select, the values in it should populate the textboxes and dropdown, can someone help me ? thanks

this is my code behind, as you can see in the LoadData() part I used the .findtext() but it outputs an error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
protected void grdRecentCases_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';this.style.cursor='Pointer'";
           e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
           e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdRecentCases, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
       }
   }


   protected void grdRecentCases_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.CommandName == "Select")
       {
           LoadData(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));

       }
   }

   ///<summary> LoadData is used to populate inputboxes with the value of the selected griview row</summary>
   ///<param name="rowNumber"> Indicates whether there is a selected row or non</param>
   private void LoadData(int? rowNumber = null)
   {
       //if rowNumber is null use GridView1.SelectedIndex
       var index = rowNumber ?? grdRecentCases.SelectedIndex;

       //Populate the input box with the value of selected row.
       GridViewRow gr = grdRecentCases.Rows[index];
       txtDepartmentCase.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
       txtLabCase.Text = gr.Cells[5].Text;
       txtIncidentReportDate.Text = gr.Cells[6].Text;
       txtCaseKey.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
       drpDepartment.Items.FindByText(gr.Cells[3].Text).Selected = true;
       drpCharge.Items.FindByText(gr.Cells[4].Text).Selected = true;

   }
```

Html code

```
<table class="style2">
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Department Case #
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartmentCase" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Department
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpDepartment" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="153px" Enabled="False"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Visible="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartment" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>


                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Charge
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCharge" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="153px" Enabled="False"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCharge_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Visible="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCharge" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>


                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Lab Case #
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLabCase" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Incident Report Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtIncidentReportDate" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any value in gr.Cells[3].Text?

Comment: as soon as I click on any row inside the gridview, the error will then execute. application will not run

Comment: In which line it shows the error?Put a breakpoint at the start of grdRecentCases_RowCommand

Comment: drpDepartment.Items.FindByText(gr.Cells[3].Text).Selected = true; here

Comment: Then you can check what is the text in gr.Cells[3].Text. Debug the code and before getting to that line hover mouse over gr.Cells[3].Text. or select it add do Quick watch or Add watch

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, to select a row in the griview and when i select, the values in it should populate the textboxes and dropdown.

Hope this can help you.
Create a datagridview event, RowHeaderMouseClick

```
     private void datagridview_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedDoc = datagridview.Rows[datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells["column name"].Value.ToString() ;

        combobox.Text = selectedDoc;
    }
```